# Template function with iterators

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, iterator

I've been trying to do Ex. 10-02 in Accelerated C++, and it was giving me errors and I eventually kept "simplifying" my program until I got to this point, and even still it wouldn't compile (via g++) giving me the error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘dumb(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)’
```

Here's my program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;    using std::endl;
using std::vector;

template <class Ran, class T> T dumb(Ran begin, Ran end)
{
    return *begin;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> myVector;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
        myVector.push_back(i);

    int d = dumb(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    cout << "Value = " << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer the return-type here. Actually there is no need to make the return-type a template-parameter here:

```
template <class Ran> typename Ran::value_type dumb(Ran begin, Ran end)
{
    return *begin;
}
```

Comment: +1, this answer is simpler and right way to deal with such containers.

Comment: Ah, nice.. my book has not yet covered the use of ::value_type yet, though I looked in the Index and it's in the next chapter.. nice clean way of fixing my problem though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the prototype of your function:

```
template <class Ran, class T> T dumb(Ran begin, Ran end)
```

When using `template`s, **return type which is dependent type (here `T`), cannot be deduced implicitly**.

So your re-designed function should be like this:

```
template <class T, class Ran>
          // ^^^^^ 'T' is coming before 'Ran'
T dumb(Ran begin, Ran end)
{
  return *begin;
}
```

and it should be called as,

```
int d = dumb<int>(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
             ^^^^
```

So we have done 2 changes:

1. The type which has to be explicitly mentioned (i.e. `T=int`) is
   coming 1st
2. Calling the `dumb<>` with explicit mention of `int`, so
       that return type is deducible

[Note: This solution is very generic for your understanding. As mentioned in @Bjorn's answer, for `vector<>` the type can be deduced automatically using `::value_type`.]

Comment: Thanks! My book did cover the use of the explicit mention when calling template functions, forgot about that. Not as clean as @Bjorn's, but works with the knowledge I (should) have so far. +1